# Alexa skip slot or set it programmatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on an Alexa skill that's basically a quiz where Alexa asks the user multiple questions in succession with the topic varying based on user state stored in a dynamo table. This works. I'm accomplishing this with an intent that has a slot for each answer and I use dialog management to elicit each response until they're all filled. Here is some of the code for that:

```
if(!answers.NewWordSpanishAnswer) {
  const newWordIntroAudio = sound('intro');
  const promptAudio = sound(`new-word-${word}-spanish-intro`);
  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(newWordIntroAudio + promptAudio)
    .reprompt(promptAudio)
    .addElicitSlotDirective('NewWordSpanishAnswer')
    .getResponse();
}

if(!answers.NewWordEnglishAnswer) {
  const responseAudio = sound(`new-word-${word}-spanish-correct`);
  const promptAudio = sound(`new-word-${word}-english-intro`);
  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(responseAudio + promptAudio)
    .reprompt(promptAudio)
    .addElicitSlotDirective('NewWordEnglishAnswer')
    .getResponse();
}

// etc. repeat for each question
```

The problem is I need to create a quiz that needs a variable number of questions, but slots are defined in the model, so I can't change the number of answers required to complete the intent. I think the way to do this is to provide some arbitrary number of `answer` slots and assign default values to the ones I don't need (so if the quiz has 3 questions, but there are 5 slots, the last 2 slots would be assigned placeholder values).

How can I accomplish this? Is there a way to set slot values programmatically?

[This Alexa blog post](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/44dd83f4-4842-40c5-91f8-3868b9f4608c/using-dialog-management-to-capture-a-and-b-or-c-slots) seems to describe what I need, but it's unfortunately written using the ASK SDK v1, so I'm not sure how to accomplish it using v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to skip 1 or more slot values.

I can think of two solutions to your problem.

1) Use **addDelegateDirective** instead of **addElicitSlotDirective** to gather slot values and fill the slots that you don't need with some arbitrary value when **dialogState** is '**STARTED**' Like the Following snippet.

```js
const { request } = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;
const { intent } = request;
if (request.dialogState === 'STARTED') {
  
  intent.slots.slotToSkip.value = 'skipped'
  
  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .addDelegateDirective(intent)
      .withShouldEndSession(false)
      .getResponse()
}
```

2) In 2nd solution you can use session variables to keep track of how many slots to elicit. Like

```js
let sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
sessionAttributes.count = 3 //Suppose you want to elicit 3 slots;
handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes);

if (sessionAttributes.count >= 0)
{
  //addElecitSlotDirective
  sessionAttributes.count = sessionAttributes.count--;
  handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes);
}
else{
  //here you will get the required number of slots
}
```

Comment: In the second solution, I would just use `withShouldEndSession` to stop the intent after I've received enough slot values? I thought about doing this, but I figured stopping an intent before all the slots were filled might cause problems. Is that not the case?

Comment: No, withShouldEndSession determines weather the current session of skill with the user should remain open or be closed after delivering the response. It has nothing to do with gathering slot values.